# How do you encrypt a password by using the RSA Algorithm?

Tags: java, encryption, rsa

I am new to encryption and I got these instructions

> Use the RSA algorithm, and use PKCS #1.5 padding (not OAEP), and add the result to the encrypted stream –this becomes the encrypted password." String os from my code is a public key.

I have imported some jars; `org-apache-commons-codec.jar` and `bcprov-jdk15-130.jar`.

For some reasons I get an error on this line `System.out.println("\n"+ "\n" +"encryptionresult" + "\n" + "\n" + Base64.toBase64String(cipher.doFinal(initiatorpassword.getBytes())) + "\n");`

The error highlights `toBase64String` only on the whole string.

> ERROR: "cannot find symbol method toBase64String."

```
import java.io.IOException;
import java.security.KeyFactory;
import java.security.NoSuchAlgorithmException;
import java.security.PublicKey;
import java.security.spec.InvalidKeySpecException;
import java.security.spec.X509EncodedKeySpec;
import javax.crypto.Cipher;
import org.bouncycastle.util.encoders.Base64;
import sun.misc.BASE64Decoder;

public class encrypt {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        encrypt obj = new encrypt();

        obj.process();
    }

    public void process() {


        try {

            String initiatorpassword = "giddibon!";    


            String os = "MIIBIjANBgkqhkiG9w0BAQEFAAOCAQ8AMIIBCgKCAQEAqLcFdVcV7HdEOotsNLoMPhD74CX1ejzcgfNuiJNy9pTySxbszRBCWxmok3Unul4rX/zyVD/6vDb9nbqRywZIgR46UOn+tR3vGXXPX6igxgS6DYTaQV8W858yOGLuoYwRi5xeQJfczAMU4o+sCxlBbMCqYs4nzW81fi8iF2OEUdrfJcbamhSnksdgfD/nomWy9MESAz1QufrOBnaRX2N0CKsi8SNmzsghpfP15VLiIVV8YXPFKtd9sY37FpY28OKGjKG5wdije/bzFL8qEcPDhqYGuVaGkhX1bkI0iH+UcFtYYrZv/Fyb5jRHXmNLiq4mMG0fMH8ENxNACFtRZTDIIQIDAQAB";


            PublicKey publickeyos = rpos(os);


            Cipher cipher = Cipher.getInstance("RSA/ECB/PKCS1Padding");


            cipher.init(Cipher.ENCRYPT_MODE, publickeyos);

             //error on this line
            System.out.println("\n"+ "\n" +"encryptionresult" + "\n" + "\n" + Base64.toBase64String(cipher.doFinal(initiatorpassword.getBytes())) + "\n");

        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    }

    public PublicKey rpos(String file) throws InvalidKeySpecException, NoSuchAlgorithmException, IOException {


        byte[] keyBytes = file.getBytes();

        String pubKey = new String(keyBytes);

        BASE64Decoder decoder = new BASE64Decoder();

        keyBytes = decoder.decodeBuffer(pubKey);

        // generate public key
        X509EncodedKeySpec spec = new X509EncodedKeySpec(keyBytes);

        KeyFactory keyFactory = KeyFactory.getInstance("RSA");

        PublicKey publicKey = keyFactory.generatePublic(spec);        

        return publicKey;

    }
}
```

Comment: which version of JDK are using , is it a compile time error ? Do you get a runtime fault , is the error part of a stacktrace ?

Comment: @RamachandranGA apparently I can not run as it has that error highlighted.  ERROR: "cannot find symbol method toBase64String."             java version "1.7.0_101"

Comment: You don't need any external JAR files for this. You can do it all within the standard JRE.

Answer (score 1):

The method you are looking for is this

**[`org.bouncycastle.util.encoders.Base64.encode(byte[] data)`](https://people.eecs.berkeley.edu/~jonah/bc/org/bouncycastle/util/encoders/Base64.html#encode(byte[]))**

I'm not sure where you got the reference to `Base64.toBase64String`, but a quick search shows that is very close to a similar C# method.

Comment: Yes! I tried this and I was able to compile but the output is rather a very short string of characters! From what I have read should be a long one. Should also be dynamic- changes every time you run the program unlike with this method! Thanks though!

Comment: This resolves your compilation problem, which was the error. I don't know how to help with your other issue

Comment: And I don't know about dynamic-ness. You are encoding to Base64, which is repeatable and reversible. It is **not** encrypting anything.

Answer (score -1):

I guess you will have to use the methoad as below and check if it compiles

```
Base64.getEncoder().encodeToString(cipher.doFinal(initiatorpassword.getBytes()))
```

Comment: Tried that but does not work too!

Comment: Whats the error you get ?

Comment: getEncoder() is highlighted ....cannot find symbol method getEncoder.

Comment: Both the following SOP's work System.out.println(java.util.Base64.getEncoder().encode("Some String".getBytes()));
  System.out.println(org.bouncycastle.util.encoders.Base64.encode("Some String".getBytes()));

Comment: @RamachandranGA `java.util.Base64` is not available in Java 7

Comment: @cricket_007 , my bad you are right. The bouncy castle one should work though

Comment: Yeah, *should*, but see comments on my answer for why he/she thinks it doesn't