# Python how to encode with RSA using modulus + exponent

Tags: python, python-3.x, rsa, python-cryptography

Hello i need to encode text with RSA using modulus and exponent + input

I have tried this, but am getting errors

```
            rsa_modulus = data['publickey_mod']
            rsa_exponent = data['publickey_exp']
            rsa_timestamp = data['timestamp']
            rsa_publickey = rsa.PublicKey(rsa_modulus, rsa_exponent)
            encrypted = rsa.encrypt(password,rsa_publickey)
            print(encrypted)
```

AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'bit_length'

Comment: Nobody here has any idea about what `data` contains, nor can we determine which line is raising that exception, so it will be hard to help. In fact, we don't *really* know what crypto library you're using either. Perhaps you can add some clarification.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to encode your `password`:

```
encrypted = rsa.encrypt(password.encode('utf8'), rsa_publickey)
```

`rsa.Encrypt` takes a byte object

Comment: should i transfer rsa_publickey to byte object too ?

Comment: I didnt need to when i recreated the issue

Answer (score 1):

Hopefully you are doing this as a demonstration, and not for an actual security critical application. Because using just RSA in this manner without any random padding is not secure.

See [How do you encrypt a password by using the RSA Algorithm?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38710910/how-do-you-encrypt-a-password-by-using-the-rsa-algorithm)